# How does Ruby functions return a value even when there is nothing to return?

Tags: ruby

Below code converts the provided key's value in an array of hashes from JSON to hash if it is not `nil`. This is demonstrated in **example 1**.

In **example 2** the provided key is `nil` therefore no changes are made to the data. This is the behavior I want. However I can't understand why this is happening. In example 2, the code doesn't hit line `if !hash[key].nil?` which means the function must return `nil` however it appears to be returning `data_2`. In ruby I understand that functions return the last evaluated statement. In example 2 what exactly is the last evaluated statement?

```rb
require 'json'

def convert(arr_of_hashes, key)
  arr_of_hashes.each do |hash|
    if !hash[key].nil?
      begin
        JSON.parse(hash[key])  
      rescue JSON::ParserError => e  
        raise "Bad"
      else
        hash[key] = JSON.parse(hash[key], {:symbolize_names => true})
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
data_1 = [ { :key_1 => "Apple", :key_2 => "{\"one\":1, \"two\":2}", :key_3 => 200 }, { :key_1 => "Orange" } ]

data_2 = [ { :key_1 => "Apple", :key_2 => nil, :key_3 => 200 }, { :key_1 => "Orange" } ]

# Example 1
p convert(data_1, :key_2)
# [{:key_1=>"Apple", :key_2=>{:one=>1, :two=>2}, :key_3=>200}, {:key_1=>"Orange"}]

# Example 2
p convert(data_2, :key_4)
# [{:key_1=>"Apple", :key_2=>nil, :key_3=>200}, {:key_1=>"Orange"}]
```

Comment: BTW you don't need `begin` / `rescue` / `else` here

Comment: It's not just example 2. Where do you think the return value in example 1 comes from? _Both_ examples return the first argument. The only difference is that example 1 modifies a hash within the array and example 2 doesn't. But in either case, the passed-in array is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider an extremely basic example:

```
irb(main):003:0> a = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):004:0> a.each { |x| p x }
1
2
3
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):005:0>
```

The `#each` method
is returning the `Enumerable` object.

If I wrap this in a method, the method returns the last expression, which evaluates to the `Enumerable` object `a`.

```
irb(main):006:0> def foo(a)
irb(main):007:1>   a.each { |x| puts x }
irb(main):008:1> end
=> :foo
irb(main):009:0> foo([1, 2, 3])
1
2
3
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):010:0>
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now! Would you say it's cleaner to explicitly return the data in the `else` part of the if-else statement or leave the code as it is?

Comment: Using `return` in Ruby will immediately exit the method and return a value (or `nil` if you just call `return`. You should probably only use it if you are explicitly trying to exit early from a method.